# Active Admin Text Editors Image Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using active admins gem to control admin's activities. I have a page named CustomPage where my inputs are heading(string) and Contents(text). For contents a text editor appears in admins page. Inside that i can insert a image. Its something like this..
[image]

Is there any way that i can modify it..like giving a and search for images localy.. Like the one with which we do in active admin.

Or is there a way to edit this text editor..(What i mean is to bring a pic upload using paperclip inside this text editor.. not as a separate field.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!!! 
gem tinymce-rails-imageupload !!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using TinyMCE (as per your screenshot), you can achieve it with tinymce `file_browser_callback` option:

JS:

```
tinymce.init({ 
    //your regular options
    plugins: "image", //and any other plugins you may have
    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        title: "My file browser",
        url: "/gallery",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Close',
          onclick: 'close',
          window : win,
          input : field_name
        }]
      }, {
        oninsert: function(url) {
          win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
      });
    }
});
```

In your `routes.rb`, create a route to the URL you want to fetch your images from. In my case:

```
get 'gallery' => 'photos#gallery'
```

In your controller add a `:layout => false` to render your image gallery properly. In my case it would be in `photos_controller.rb`:

```
def gallery
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :layout => false }
    end
end
```

And then you can create and style the gallery popup you'll use to select your images from the way you want it. Here is an excerpt of one that I did. The key is of course not to forget to use a JS script to send back the info to your editor. In my case, it would be under Views > Photos < gallery.html.erb :

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        //style your image gallery here
    </style>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("li").on("click", function(){
                top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert($(this).attr("data-url"));
                top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="image_browser">
    <% Photo.order("updated_at desc").all.each do |a| %>
        <li data-url="<%= a.image.url %>">
            <%= image_tag a.image.url(:thumb) %>
            <p><%= a.title %></p>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Of course you can sort and filter the photo you're fetching any way you want. And of course, you can also style and create your gallery popup any way you want too.

In your image selector you'll then have a little browsing icon next to your source field:

[image]

On click, you should have the little photo gallery we just created where you can select which one to use:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: NO i want to upload files from my computer not from a gallery

Comment: What I do is that I have a dedicated 'Photo' section in ActiveAdmin where I can upload pictures. That way can re-use some that I already uploaded before. You could definitely add a "File Upload" button in the popup, where it would trigger an Photo upload.